# Не работает пакет в виртуальной среде Python VS Code

Tags: python

Всем привет, я недавно начала изучать Python и сейчас подошла к теме использования пакетов в виртуальной среде. Я создала виртуальную среду в папке .venv и хочу запустить такой код:

```py
import requests

my_request = requests.get('https://www.python.org')
print(my_request)
```

В выходе вижу:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\marin\Python\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Затем я перехожу в терминал и ввожу pwd чтобы получить полный путь к текущей папке main.py

```
PS C:\Users\marin\Python> pwd

Path
----
C:\Users\marin\Python
```

Дальше по инструкции перехожу в настройки Code-runner Executor Map --> Edit in settings.json

Далее в файле json, в строке "python" необходимо указать абсолютный путь к интерпретатору python в виртуальной среде C:\Users\marin\Python.venv\bin\python -u
чтобы перезапустить исходный код и получить ответ (содержимое объекта 'my_request').

И сразу же settings.json пишет "Invalid escape character in string.jsonc(261)", если же поменять на обратный слэш "C:/Users/marin/Python/.venv/bin/python" то в выводе получу "The system cannot find the path specified."

Мне нужно в settings.json проложить путь к папке .venv к файлу python. В видеоуроке у преподавателя есть подпапка "bin" где и находится файл python но у меня такой папки нет (у меня windows, в уроке mac). В общем, я окончательно запуталась и гугл не смог ответить на мой вопрос((
[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Окружение вы можете выбрать нажав на правый нижний угол окна VSC, где у вас написано, какое сейчас выбрано виртуальное окружение "Python 3.12" и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ найден:
я неправильно проложила путь в файле settings.json
Все из-за того что мой файл python в папке .venv выглядит таким образом:
"python": "C:/Users/marin/Python/.venv/Scripts/python -u"

Comment: Отметьте этот ответ как [**принятый**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) (галка напротив ответа).